# GREP error: warning: cannot select font 'i'

Tags: grep, man, groff

I am in the process of learning the usage of iscsiadm and somehow I noticed a strange behavior of `grep`.

Attempting to run the following grep command `man iscsiadm | grep "aia"` results in `troff:<standard input>:498: warning: cannot select font 'i'`.

I played around and found out that the error does not occur when I grep for `ia` or `ai`, therefore, it must be caused by the specific pattern `aia`.

Can anyone offer an explanation for this behavior?

**EDIT**

@telcoM

I ran both command and both files contain the same error; They are in fact equal and yes, I don't see the error message in the console any longer. Both files contain the same error message as before.

@TheNotoriousGBR

It seems like you are right. I ran the command `zgrep '\\fi' $(man -w iscsiadm)` and in fact the capital "I" is missing:

```
\fiSNS\fR supported depends on build options, but is enabled by default.
```

Based on the previous result, it seems like the issue is not related to `grep` as many of you suggested but lies in fact inside the `man` page of iscsiadm itself.

Should I let the title be as it is or change it to a more suitable one?

Comment: Try `man iscsiadm 2>/tmp/test1.txt | grep "aia"`, then `man iscsiadm 2>/tmp/test2.txt | grep "ia"`. In both cases, you should no longer see the error, because the error messages are redirected to a text file; if you still see it, something **very** strange is happening. Then compare the files `/tmp/test1.txt` and `/tmp/test2.txt`. Are they in fact both the same, or different? (Please *edit your question* to add this information; leave a comment only if you have a problem doing what was asked.) I'll write a more complete answer once I'll know the results of this test.

Comment: As @telcoM has noted, this one is very strange.  See my answer below.

Comment: @eyoung100 Essentially, my first guess was that there is something in the `iscsiadm` man page that always triggers the error, but it doesn't come visible when grepping for `ia` or `ai` because the partial output from the man page formatter process overwrites the error message on screen. But when the man page output is further constrained by `grep "aia"`, the error won't get overwritten on screen and can be seen. The test suggested in my first comment should prove that the error is not related to `grep` but to the `man` command and its man page formatting process chain.

Comment: @telcoM As noted RE: My sentence "Troff is the default formatter for man." We're both in the same alley.  This one is a strange one!

Comment: @eyoung100 Indeed. My intention was to first fix the asker's apparent misunderstanding that the error message was related to `grep`, and then unpack the rest of the relationship between `man` and `troff` once that was confirmed. You drilled right down into the root cause, but as a result, unless the asker reads it very carefully or already knows a bit about how `man` works, your answer standing alone could have left the asker thinking "well and good, but how is this related to my error message from `grep`"?

Comment: @telcoM This brings up an interesting side question related to editing questions.  I'm only asking because I attempt to help a lot of posters at any given time.  I could easily re-tag this using `groff` as the tag, or even the `man` tag, but do you lead posters as you have done here, or do you get right to the answer more often?

Comment: @eyoung100 Your answer is great; you probably know more about `troff` than me. But given that the question title begins with "GREP error", I think it might be beneficial to just add something like "The error does not come from `grep` but from `troff` which is used by `man` to format the man page" somewhere near the beginning of your answer to fix the asker's initial misunderstanding. Since they have no rep to speak of, I decided to try a newbie-friendly step-by-step approach in this case, and perhaps teach how SE differs from discussion forums at the same time.

Comment: @telcoM  Thanks!  Makes perfect sense

Comment: @OP: If the problem is identified as not being related to `grep` then please edit the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in my comments to eyoung100 (EDIT: in a now-deleted answer), I don't see this problem with Debian's open-scsi 2.1.3-5 package.  Also, there are no font selection escape sequences (or requests) on line 498 of my copy of that document, so you are almost certainly using another version.

My copy formats without warnings:

```
$ nroff -ww -man -z ./doc/iscsiadm.8
```

(I used `-ww` to turn on all warnings and `-z` to suppress formatted output, since all I am interested in are diagnostic messages.)

I do see, at line 503 of my copy of the *doc/iscsiadm.8* file, the following:

```
like you would in node mode, run \fIiscsiadm \-m fw\fR.
```

If I delete the capital I, I get the following.

```
$ nroff -ww -man -z ./doc/iscsiadm.8
troff:./doc/iscsiadm.8:503: warning: cannot select font 'i'
```

I therefore think something similar is happening with your copy.

You might try this:

```
$ zgrep '\\fi' $(man -w iscsiadm)
```

That should tell you if the page has the error I suspect.

One might wonder why the error happens.  It is due to the syntax of the font selection escape sequence `\f`.  Here's how *groff*(7) summarizes it.

```
     \fP     Select previous font mounting position (abstract style or
             font); same as “.ft” or “.ft P”.
     \fF     Select font mounting position, abstract style, or font with
             one‐character name or one‐digit position F.  F cannot be P.
     \f(ft   Select font mounting position, abstract style, or font with
             two‐character name or two‐digit position ft.
     \f[font]
             Select font mounting position, abstract style, or font with
             arbitrarily long name or position font.  font cannot be P.
     \f[]    Select previous font mounting position (abstract style or
             font).
```

The square-bracket forms are GNU *troff* extensions to the AT&T *troff* language.  (They might actually originate in SoftQuad *troff*, a now nearly forgotten descendant of AT&T's Documenter's Workbench 2.0 *troff*.)

So when you have `\f` followed by something other than an opening parenthesis `(` or opening square bracket `[`, the next character is interpreted as the name of the font to be selected.  (It could also be a single-digit *font mounting position*, but this usage is vanishingly rare in *man*(7) pages--fortunately.)

As far as *groff* is concerned, terminals support only four font names: `R`, `I`, `B`, and `BI`; the *grotty*(1) man page says more.  Attempting to select any other font name will fail; like much else in Unix, *roff font names are case-sensitive.   *groff* 1.23.0 started issuing diagnostics upon font selection failure in many more cases than earlier versions of *groff* did.